# How to pass custom template to angular dialog

Tags: angular, templates, dialog

I'm new to angular, I wish to create a "generic" dialog with title, and message, and it takes in random "content". (I do not wish to pass raw Html and use innerHTML). It's easier to illustrate in React,

```
function Dialog(props){
  return <div><h1>{props.title}</h1><p>{props.message}</p>
    {props.children}    <-   this
  </div>
}

....
ReactDOM.render(<Dialog ...>
  <p class='custom'>This is custom content!</p>  <-- passing custom template
</Dialog>, ...)
```

I know that there is < ng-content >. But how do I pass random templates (not raw html) in :

```
MatDialog.open(<Component>, <options>)
```

so that I can use it in dialog.component.html like:

```
<div>{{data.title}}</div>
<p>{{data.message}}</div>
** <ng-content></ng-content> **
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far>

Comment: you can pass your title, message or content to second parameter of `open` function. refer stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after spending a week on angular, found a solution. It's "ngTemplateOutlet":

in dialog:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="data.content"></ng-container>
```

in the caller's template, define:

```
<ng-template #someContent><mat-icon>warning</mat-icon>Warning</ng-template>
```

in the caller's component, open dialog:

```
@ViewChild("someContent") someContent : TemplateRef<any>
onDelete(){ 
  this.dialog.open(<>, { data:{content:this.someContent, ...}, ... }) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Using **DomSanitizer**

---

### dialog.component.html

```
<h3 matDialogTitle>Here is my Dialog</h3>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div [innerHtml]="innerHtml"></div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

### dialog.component.ts

```
innerHtml : string
```

### app-component.html

```
<button (click)="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
```

### app-component.ts

```
  htmlContent: string = '<p>Here is your content</p>';

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private dom: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent)

    dialogRef.componentInstance.innerHtml = this.dom.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.htmlContent);
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-kaub3n?file=app/app.component.ts)

## Here is another way to handle the dialogBox

---

You can mange another comoponent for your all the notifications

alert-dialog-component.ts

```
<div class="notification-dialog">
  <h1>{{ data.title }}</h1>

  <div class="content-area">
    <div mat-dialog-content>
      <div [innerHTML]="inneContent"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions" mat-dialog-actions>

      <span *ngIf="data.dialogType === 'yesno'">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close()">No</button>
        <button mat-raised-button>Yes</button>
      </span>

      <span *ngIf="data.dialogType === 'ok'">
        <button mat-raised-button>OK</button>
      </span>

      <span *ngIf="data.dialogType === 'yesnocancel'">
        <button mat-raised-button>Yes</button>
        <button mat-raised-button>No</button>
        <button mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
      </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

alert-dialog.component.ts

```
    dialogType: notificationDialogType;
      buttons: notificationButtons;
      notificationType: notificationDialogType;
    
   constructor(
     public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AlertDialogComponent>,
     private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
     @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: notificationDialogData
    ) {}
   }
    
   export enum notificationDialogType {
      ok = 'ok',
      cancel = 'cancel',
      yesno = 'yesno',
      yesnocancel = 'yesnocancel',
    }
    
    export enum notificationType {
      error = 'error',
      warn = 'warn',
      success = 'success',
    }
    
    export enum notificationButtons {
      ok = 'ok',
      yes = 'yes',
      cancel = 'cancel',
      no = 'no',
    }
    
    export interface notificationDialogData {
      title: string;
      html: string;
      message: string;
      dialogType: notificationDialogType;
      notificationType: notificationType;
      btnText: {
        ok: string;
        cancel: string;
        no: string;
        yes: string;
      };
```

from other components you can call the notification dialoag like this (See the stackblitz to see how it call diffrent ways)

```
  async submit(){

    try{
      await this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent, {

        data: {
          title: 'saving in progress',
          message : 'Are you sure ?',
          dialogType : notificationDialogType.yesnocancel,
          notificationType : notificationType.warn
        }

      })
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }

  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-1pcutf?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thanks for trying, but as I mentioned in the original post, cannot use raw html. i cannot pass something like
<div><mat-icon>warning</mat-icon><span>WARNING</span></div>